# React-Native Icon at createBottomTabNavigator does not appear

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am fairly new to React-Native and I am trying to implement a bottom navigation bar.

I have succeeded to do this, however, I can not seem to get the Icons working.

**Code that I am using**

```
import React from 'react';

import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import {NewsPage} from "./src/components/NewsPage";
import {TaskOverview} from "./src/components/TaskOverview";
import {Agenda} from "./src/components/Agenda";
import {Wiki} from "./src/components/Wiki";
import {Profile} from "./src/components/Profile";
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements'

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    TaskOverview: {
        screen: TaskOverview,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Example title',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Icon name="rocket" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
            )
        },
    },
    NewsPage: {
        screen: NewsPage,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Example title2',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Icon name="rocket" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
            )
        },
    },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer/>;
    }
}
```

**Result that I am getting**

It shows me bottom navigation but for the icon, it literally shows me a question mark.

**What have I tried**

- Instead of Icon, I have tried working with IonIcon, but this did not solve this issue for me.
- I tried different Icon names.

I hope someone can give me some insight.

Comment: Can you use `react-native-vector-icons`? Instead of `react-native-elements`

Comment: first can you try with loading local icon - `require('./src/assets/home.png')`. If its working, definitely you have problem with <Icon> element. then try with this `<Icon
  name='rowing' />`

Comment: try to set static color for ex. 'red' instead of `tintColor`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the  element.

I solved my icon issue by just using a local image with the following code:

```
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <Image
                    source={require('./src/assets/megaphone.png')}
                    style={{width: 26, height: 26, tintColor: tintColor}}
                />
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because "Rocket" isn't part of the `Material` icons package.

Full list of Material icons is here: https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

You have to use the `type` prop and use something like `font-awesome` to have the rocket:

```
<Icon name="rocket" color={"red"} size={24} type="font-awesome"/>
```

More info at: https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/1.0.0/icon.html#type